# Capturing first character on entering edit mode - custom editing control in DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm hosting a custom editing control in a `DataGridView`, which for the record is a `TextBox` and `Button` together in a `UserControl`. I have inherited from `DataGridViewColumn` for the new column and `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` for the new cell.

With a normal `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, if you press a key when the cell has focus, it will begin edit mode **and** the character you typed will appear in the `TextBoxEditingControl`. However, in my inherited cell, no value is being passed down on keypress. (In fact, you have to manually pass the current cell value in `InitializeEditingControl` or nothing will show up at all.) So, the first character you type (the one that begins edit mode) is lost.

I have tried `OnKeyPress`, `OnKeyDown`, and `OnKeyUp` in the `DataGridViewCell` but they never get called. `KeyEntersEditMode`, however, does seem to get called, and only when it is checking against a pressed key, so this might be a good place to start. The problem then becomes how to translate a KeyEventArgs to a `char`. This is trivial for alphabet and numbers, but since not all keyboards are created equal, handling other keys is messy and complicated at best. If there's a converter class that will do this automagically, please enlighten me.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or found a good workaround?

Note: This problem applies when `EditMode` is set to any variation of `EditOnKeystroke`. Setting to `EditOnEnter` is a valid workaround for my project, but I'd like to emulate the default behavior of the `TextBoxEditingControl` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the KeyPreview of the user control to true. Then check if the key which starts the editing process fires the keydown even for the user control. If it does, you can simply store and assign the character once the text control enters edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution is to override `OnKeyPress` on the custom `UserControl`.

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  _textBox.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
  _textBox.SelectionStart = 1;
  _textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
  base.OnKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: Does the UserControl get the keypress passed down to it from the DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Today I had the same problem. My solution is to override KeyEntersEditMode in CustomCell and put there some algorithm to convert or to determine if a character is valid for passing to the editing control. Then I store this value as a private variable. I override the InitializeEditingControl method and use my stored value as the initial value for the control. After using it I set it to null so that later nothing would use it.

```
private string startString;
public override bool KeyEntersEditMode(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var result = base.KeyEntersEditMode(e);
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.D1)
    {
        startString = "1";
    }
    return result;
}

public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
{
    if(startString != null)
    {
        initialFormattedValue = startString;
        startString = null;
    }
    base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
    var c = this.DataGridView.EditingControl as MyEditingControl;
    string initialFormattedValueStr = initialFormattedValue as string;
    if (initialFormattedValueStr == null)
    {
        c.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        c.Text = initialFormattedValueStr;
        c.SelectionStart = initialFormattedValueStr.Length;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first character into your TextBox do this:

1) Add "Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices" or using if you prefer C#

2) Add mapping to SendMessage in user32.dll

```
VB.Net example:
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

C# example:
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

3) Redirect the key to your TextBox from UserControl

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessKeyEventArgs(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean
    SendMessage(Me.ComboBox.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam)
    Return True
End Function

protected override bool ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref Message m)
{
    SendMessage(textBox.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
    return true;
}
```

4) There is [example on Microsoft page with the DataGridViewNumericUpDown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), download the source.

5) Done.